# Ads script: any easy way to get an ad hierarchy?

Tags: ads, google-ads-script

Say I have an `Ad` object. I want to see its hierarchy (MCC account, sub-MCC account, account, Campaign, AdGroup). Is there any easy way to get it?

Propagating up won't be easy because I don't know it the account has a sub-MCC account ancestor.

Is there any [Ad url](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_adurls) that shows the hierarchy?

Or any other way?